# How do I search for LibreOffice/OpenOffice files which contain specific text?

Tags: gui, files, search

I am trying to locate a LibreOffice/OpenOffice file which contains some text, but I don't know the file name.

Is there any possible way to locate said file using the Ubuntu's search file tool? If so, how?  It seems that the search tool under *Places* only looks into plain text files. How should I proceed without using the command prompt?

Comment: you could also use the script i posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757578/command-line-tool-to-search-docx-file-under-ms-dos-or-cygwin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### GUI

Install `searchmonkey`, it's available from the repositories.
It's easy enough, but if you still need some help with it, ask me and I'll see if I can figure it out for you.

### Command Line

```
grep -R -i -a -n needle stack
```

`grep` is the tool needed to find text.
`-R` tells `grep` to search recursively.
`-i` tells `grep` to not be case-sensitive.
`-a` tells `grep` to treat binary files as plain text files.
`-n` tells `grep` to show you the line number where the needle is in the file.
*needle* is the piece of text you are looking for.
*stack* is where it should search. Because of the `-R` parameter you can use a directory here.

**Example**

```
grep -R -i -a -n "<html>" Websites
```

This will search for the text  in every file in the folder *Websites*

I hope my explanation was enough for you to understand the use of all parameters. If not, feel free to ask more in a comment.

Comment: so there is no GUI tool in Ubuntu for finding files containing text?

Comment: Ow xD `How should I proceed without using the command prompt?`, thought it said `How should I proceed using the command prompt?`. My mistake, I'll look for a GUI tool.

Comment: Got one, just tested `searchmonkey`. Seems to be a great application wich I'll probably be using a lot myself from now on :p

Comment: thanks for the tip about searchmonkey. However, it doesn't find seem to find any files with my needle. Whereas, the grep command does seem to work.  Just trying to find a tool for a friend who is not comfortable with command line operations.

Comment: My guess is that searchmonkey isn't able to find it, because it's a binary file... Maybe you've got more succes with this one? http://sourceforge.net/projects/grepgui/

Comment: So, outside of using grep on the command line Ubuntu doesn't have a built in GUI tool for locating binary files containing specific peices of text.

Comment: thanks for the tip on grepgui will try it out. I  was hoping for some built in tool or trick.

Answer (score 0):

Since LibreOffice/OpenOffice are basically XMLs inside a ZIP, for e.g. for ODTs:

```sh
find . -name "*.odt" -exec bash -c "echo \"{}\" && zipgrep -io mypattern \"{}\"" \;
```

This will work for any [OpenDocument (ODF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) or [Microsoft's OOXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) files.

I don't know how `grep` as-is could be of any help.